# How to update a map value that is inside another map (ELIXIR)

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir, I need to change a value of a map that is inside another map.

For example:

```
test = %{"test1" => %{"test11" => 0}, "test2" => %{"test22" => 0}}
```

I tried:

```
test = Map.put(test["test1"], "test11", 1)
```

Returns:

```
%{"test11" => 1}
```

But I need:

```
%{"test1" => %{"test11" => 1}, "test2" => %{"test22" => 0}}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is immutable.

```rb
test =
  %{"test1" => %{"test11" => 0},
    "test2" => %{"test22" => 0}}
```

by calling `Map.put(test["test1"], "test11", 1)` you don’t modify anything, you put the value into `test["test1"]` and return the result back.

Use [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) (or [`update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) to update) that uses [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) implementation under the hood.

```rb
put_in(test, ["test1", "test11"], 1)
#⇒ %{"test1" => %{"test11" => 1},
#    "test2" => %{"test22" => 0}}
```

Comment: Also `put_in(test["test1"]["test11"], 1)`